# Iterating through JSON array in Shell script

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON data as follows in data.json file

```
[
  {"original_name":"pdf_convert","changed_name":"pdf_convert_1"},
  {"original_name":"video_encode","changed_name":"video_encode_1"},
  {"original_name":"video_transcode","changed_name":"video_transcode_1"}
]
```

I want to iterate through the array and extract the value for each element in a loop. I saw [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). I find it difficult to use it to iterate. How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like `jq` has a `foreach` command, have you tried that?

Comment: Honestly, I think you'd be much more satisfied with a simple Python script. You can even embed it into your shell script using heredoc syntax.

Comment: Can you give an example of embedding python into a shell script?

Answer (score 178):

Just use a filter that would return each item in the array.  Then loop over the results, just make sure you use the compact output option (`-c`) so each result is put on a single line and is treated as one item in the loop.

```
jq -c '.[]' input.json | while read i; do
    # do stuff with $i
done
```

Comment: A `for` loop iterates over whitespace-separated words, not lines.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, though in this specific case, it would have been ok since there were no spaces in any of the objects. But the idea is still the same, the looping mechanism was probably the wrong choice.

Comment: jq outputs a stream, so you are not going line by line or item by item.

Comment: If your output contains spaces, you'll need to set your IFS to a newline, e.g with Bash `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: works for me (Big Sur on Mac). here's what I got so far: `echo "$res" | jq -c -r '.[]' | while read item; do
    val=$(jq -r '.value' <<< "$item")
    echo "Value: $val"
done`

Comment: But, i've found if you're doing stuff like adding to an array within the while loop, you'll need to modify it like `done < <(echo "$res" | jq -c -r '.[]')` instead of piping the output to `while`. See here for more info https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2031

Comment: @JeffMercado I've been using this pretty easily that is until I started calling helper functions in my loop iterations. First one runs fine and then the loop just dies. But echo actually just iterated everything

Answer (score 27):

By leveraging the power of Bash arrays, you can do something like:

```bash
# read each item in the JSON array to an item in the Bash array
readarray -t my_array < <(jq --compact-output '.[]' input.json)

# iterate through the Bash array
for item in "${my_array[@]}"; do
  original_name=$(jq --raw-output '.original_name' <<< "$item")
  changed_name=$(jq --raw-output '.changed_name' <<< "$item")
  # do your stuff
done
```

Comment: "Power of Bash Arrays! ⚡️" - It's too much man.

Comment: note to macOS users - this will not work 'out of the box' due to apple sticking with an older version of bash due to licensing (currently v3.2.57).  you can use homebrew to obtain the latest version.  You will need to set the newer version as your default shell or set your script to use it explicitly with a shebang

Comment: Good to know! That must be why macOS switched to ZSH so.

Comment: And if reading from a variable instead:   
`readarray -t my_array < <(jq -c '.[]' <<< $input_json)`

Comment: This is only solution that works out of box. All the others are concepts that need serious correcting to work!

Comment: Did not work out-of-the-box for me.. I'm seeing: `syntax error near unexpected token ‘<‘`.  Anyone else? So its complaining on the second "<" on the `readarray` command.

Comment: For me it's working just fine, Bash 5.1.16.

Answer (score 24):

`jq` has a shell formatting option: `@sh`.

You can use the following to format your json data as shell parameters:

```
cat data.json | jq '. | map([.original_name, .changed_name])' | jq @sh
```

The output will look like:

```
"'pdf_convert' 'pdf_convert_1'"
"'video_encode' 'video_encode_1'",
"'video_transcode' 'video_transcode_1'"
```

To process each row, we need to do a couple of things:

- Set the bash for-loop to read the entire row, rather than stopping at the first space (default behavior).
- Strip the enclosing double-quotes off of each row, so each value can be passed as a parameter to the function which processes each row.

To read the entire row on each iteration of the bash for-loop, set the `IFS` variable, as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces).

To strip off the double-quotes, we'll run it through the bash shell interpreter using `xargs`:

```
stripped=$(echo $original | xargs echo)
```

---

Putting it all together, we have:

```
#!/bin/bash

function processRow() {
  original_name=$1
  changed_name=$2

  # TODO
}

IFS=$'\n' # Each iteration of the for loop should read until we find an end-of-line
for row in $(cat data.json | jq '. | map([.original_name, .changed_name])' | jq @sh)
do
  # Run the row through the shell interpreter to remove enclosing double-quotes
  stripped=$(echo $row | xargs echo)

  # Call our function to process the row
  # eval must be used to interpret the spaces in $stripped as separating arguments
  eval processRow $stripped
done
unset IFS # Return IFS to its original value
```

Comment: You can use the `--raw-output` or `-r` flag to exclude the enclosing double quotes, instead of having to 'strip the enclosing double quotes', replacing `jq @sh` with `jq -r @sh`

Comment: You don't (currently) need a shell pipe through a second jq; it works fine to just append `| @sh` in the jq pipeline.  As in `jq -r '. | map(blah) | @sh'`

Answer (score 17):

From [Iterate over json array of dates in bash (has whitespace)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635875/iterate-over-json-array-of-dates-in-bash-has-whitespace)

```
items=$(echo "$JSON_Content" | jq -c -r '.[]')
for item in ${items[@]}; do
    echo $item
    # whatever you are trying to do ...
done
```

Comment: Why doesn't `echo ${items[1]}` show a result?

Comment: did not work for me (Mac Big Sur). Only one loop iteration for a list with multiple items. @JeffMercado's answer did work, however.

Comment: This is quite buggy: Your `items` is an _string_, not an array, even if you try to use array syntax to iterate over it.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me on Mac

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example that works in *zch* shell:

```
DOMAINS='["google","amazon"]'

arr=$(echo $DOMAINS | jq -c '.[]')
for d in $arr; do
    printf "Here is your domain: ${d}\n"
done
```

Comment: This code doesn’t work because you don’t quote `$DOMAINS` in `echo` so Bash interprets `[` as a command and fails. Even if you fixes this, it still breaks if you have a space in one of the domains.

Comment: sorry. i should have specified that my shell is zch. It works in that shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try Build it around this example. (Source: Original Site)

Example:

```
jq '[foreach .[] as $item ([[],[]]; if $item == null then [[],.[0]]     else [(.[0] + [$item]),[]] end; if $item == null then .[1] else empty end)]'
```

`Input  [1,2,3,4,null,"a","b",null]`

`Output [[1,2,3,4],["a","b"]]`

Comment: The original question is vague, but I don't think `foreach` is at all necessary for wha the user wants.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here worked for me, out-of-the-box.

What did work was a combination of a few:

```
projectList=$(echo "$projRes" | jq -c '.projects[]')

IFS=$'\n' # Read till newline

for project in ${projectList[@]}; do
  projectId=$(jq '.id' <<< "$project")
  projectName=$(jq -r '.name' <<< "$project")
  ...
done

unset IFS
```

NOTE: I'm not using the same data as the question does, in this example assume `projRes` is the output from an API that gives us a JSON list of projects, eg:

```
{
  "projects": [ 
    {"id":1,"name":"Project"}, 
    ... // array of projects
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An earlier answer in this thread suggested using jq's `foreach`, but that may be much more complicated than needed, especially given the stated task. Specifically, `foreach` (and `reduce`) are intended for certain cases where you need to accumulate results.

In many cases (including some cases where eventually a reduction step is necessary), it's better to use `.[]` or `map(_)`.  The latter is just another way of writing [.[] | _] so if you are going to use jq, it's really useful to understand that .[] simply creates a *stream* of values.
For example, `[1,2,3] | .[]` produces a stream of the three values.

To take a simple map-reduce example, suppose you want to find the maximum length of an array of strings.  One solution would be `[ .[] | length] | max`.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, [@Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952539/2158479) is the way to go. It uses jq's `--compact-output` (or `-c`) flag to print each iteration result on its own single line, then uses the shell's `read` function in a `while` loop to linewise read the results into a shell variable.

```bash
jq -c '.[]' input.json | while read i; do
    # do stuff with $i
done
```

But utilizing that flag comes at the cost of sacrificing the pretty-printing otherwise present in jq's non-compact outputs. If you needed that formatting, the proximate attempt would be to subsequently run other instances of jq on each iteration step to (re-)establish the formatting for each output. However, this can be expensive, especially on large input arrays, and could be generally avoided by retaining the initial formatting while using a delimiter other than the newline character (because the pretty-printed, multi-line output items themselves already do contain newlines characters).

As `bash` is tagged, one way would be using `read`'s (non-POSIX) `-d` option to provide a custom delimiter. With an empty string, it defaults to "terminate a line when it reads a NUL character", which can be added to jq's output using `"\u0000"`. As for the jq filter, opening a new context (with `|`) after the iteration ensures it's printed with every array item. Finally, jq's `--join-output` (or `-j`) flag decodes the JSON-encoded NUL character while suppressing the otherwise appended newline characters after each item.

```bash
jq -j '.[] | ., "\u0000"' input.json | while read -d '' i; do
    # do stuff with pretty-printed, multi-line "$i"
done
```

**Edit**: With [jq 1.7](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.7), a new flag `--raw-output0` (note the `0` at the end) was introduced, which behaves just like the regular `--raw-output` (or `-r`) flag, but emits NUL characters instead of newlines after each output printed. It thus perfectly covers the last approach while rendering all its manual arrangements (adding `"\u0000"` and using the `-j` flag) unnecessary.

```bash
jq --raw-output0 '.[]' input.json | while read -d '' i; do
    # do stuff with pretty-printed, multi-line "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using `jq` and started using `jp`, since JMESpath is the same language as used by the `--query` argument of my cloud service and I find it difficult to juggle both languages at once. You can quickly learn the basics of JMESpath expressions here: https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html

Since you didn't **specifically** ask for a `jq` answer but instead, an approach to iterating JSON in bash, I think it's an appropriate answer.

**Style points:**

1. I use backticks and those have fallen out of fashion. You can substitute with another command substitution operator.
2. I use `cat` to pipe the input contents into the command. Yes, you can also specify the filename as a parameter, but I find this distracting because it breaks my left-to-right reading of the sequence of operations. Of course you can update this from my style to yours.
3. `set -u` has no function in this solution, but is important if you are fiddling with bash to get something to work. The command forces you to declare variables and therefore doesn't allow you to misspell a variable name.

Here's how I do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

# exploit the JMESpath length() function to get a count of list elements to iterate
export COUNT=`cat data.json | jp "length( [*] )"`

# The `seq` command produces the sequence `0 1 2` for our indexes
# The $(( )) operator in bash produces an arithmetic result ($COUNT minus one)
for i in `seq 0 $((COUNT - 1))` ; do

     # The list elements in JMESpath are zero-indexed
     echo "Here is element $i:"
     cat data.json | jp "[$i]"

     # Add or replace whatever operation you like here.

done
```

Now, it would also be a common use case to pull the original JSON data from an online API and not from a local file. In that case, I use a slightly modified technique of caching the full result in a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

# cache the JSON content in a stack variable, downloading it only once
export DATA=`api --profile foo compute instance list --query "bar"`

export COUNT=`echo "$DATA" | jp "length( [*] )"`
for i in `seq 0 $((COUNT - 1))` ; do
     echo "Here is element $i:"
     echo "$DATA" | jp "[$i]"
done
```

This second example has the added benefit that if the data is changing rapidly, you are guaranteed to have a consistent count between the elements you are iterating through, and the elements in the iterated data.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are receiving some problems, it might be related to the transformed escape character `\"` being parsed to just `"`, which will result in error:

**parse error: Invalid escape at line ...**

My solution to this problem is using `sed`. So, if we would transform the query from one of the previous answers, the command would look like this:

```
jq -c '.[]' input.json | sed 's/\\"/\\'\''/g' | while read i; do
    # do stuff with $i | jq
done
```

where the command `sed 's/\\"/\\'\''/g'` would replace all `\"` with `'`.

There might be different parsing error scenarios when iterating through the objects. If there would I would adjust the sed command to make the JSON syntax valid.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have done so far

```
 arr=$(echo "$array" | jq -c -r '.[]')
            for item in ${arr[@]}; do
               original_name=$(echo $item | jq -r '.original_name')
               changed_name=$(echo $item | jq -r '.changed_name')
              echo $original_name $changed_name
            done
```

Comment: When accessing the value of a key, instead of uisng `. original_name` with no quotes, should it be `original_name =$(echo $item | jq -r '.original_name')`? Also, why is there a space before `=`?

Comment: I don't see how this works at all unless you have `IFS=$'\n'` set before running it, or your JSON objects contain no spaces. And even if you _do_ set IFS, it's still buggy due to the unquoted expansion; if this is run by a shell with `nullglob` or `globfail` flags active you'll get surprises when your JSON contains wildcard characters.