# Iterate over json array of dates in bash (has whitespace)

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I have an array that is being stored in a bash variable that is a json array of dates (it's currently being produced by a separate script).  It looks like the following

```
["2019-09-19 03:13:29", "2019-09-19 20:20:18", "2019-09-19 18:19:50", "2019-09-19 06:07:17", "2019-09-19 11:53:25"]
```

I want to iterate over these dates and preserve the white space in the dates so I can use them with the `gdate` command.  I'm currently using `jq` but that is splitting up the date part from the time part.  i.e.

```
dates=$(python date_producing_script.py | jq -c -r '.[]')
for date in ${dates[@]}; do
    echo $date
    #end goal is to do something here w/ gdate ex gdate -d $date ...
done
```

However this gives something like

```
2019-09-19
03:13:29
2019-09-19
20:20:18
2019-09-19
18:19:50
2019-09-19
06:07:17
2019-09-19
11:53:25
```

Where I'm looking for something like the following

```
2019-09-19 03:13:29
2019-09-19 20:20:18
2019-09-19 18:19:50
2019-09-19 06:07:17
2019-09-19 11:53:25
```

(one confusing thing for me here is that if I just do the `python date_producing_script.py | jq -c -r '.[]'` command in a terminal it looks the way I want it to)

However ideally I would want something like.  Is there anyway to get this result from the input in shell script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jq is fine; the problem is in the way you're looping through the bash array, as can be seen from this bash typescript:

```
$ ary=("a b" "c d")
$ for x in ${ary[@]} ; do echo "$x" ; done
a
b
c
d
$ for x in "${ary[@]}" ; do echo "$x" ; done
a b
c d
$
```

### IOW

```
"${dates[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
IFS=','
dates='["2019-09-19 03:13:29", "2019-09-19 20:20:18", "2019-09-19 18:19:50", "2019-09-19 06:07:17", "2019-09-19 11:53:25"]'

for date in ${dates[@]}
do
    # Cleanup $date
    thedate=$(echo $date | tr -d '\[\]"' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
    echo "-->$thedate<--"
done
```

- IFS: sets the separator as ,
- `$dates` is now separated on ,
- `$thedate` is `$date` with `[`, `]`, `"` removed. The `sed` is to remove prefix spaces.
- I put `-->` and `<--` to show that `$thedate` does not include any spaces.

There are most probably solutions with `awk` too.

Answer (score 0):

One of your issue is when you populate `dates` array ,
and the other is when you want to use the array for loop .

My proposal is :

- change jq to generate a long string of date with `=` as a separator
- tell bash to use `=` as separator instead of `<space><tab><line return>`
- you must use the syntax `"$dates[@]"` instead of `$dates[@]`

Your script will be like :

```
OLDIFS=$IFS ;
IFS="=" ;
dates=( python date_producing_script.py | jq  -c -j -r '.[]|(.,"=")') );
IFS=$OLDIFS

for d in "${dates[@]}" ;
do 
    echo $d ;
done
```