# How to loop over items from AWS CLI output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, shell, jq

`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s`

this shows the list like this below, in this case three lines, but it can change.

```
"taskArns": [
    "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100222222:task/dev-ec2-cls/1f3761101efd439f9d8959901e8f6095",
    "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100222222:task/dev-ec2-cls/2bfb7cdfb9e64362b4df6b7f7e829236",
    "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:678100222222:task/dev-ec2-cls/408879277ab24490b1b911b119c81414",
```

then I made this script,

task id such as `408879277ab24490b1b911b119c81414` is set as environment variable and throw to next command.

```
task_id=(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s |
jq '.taskArns[0] | split(\"/\")[-1]' |
awk '{print substr($0, 2, length($0)-2)}')
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster dev-ec2-cls --tasks "$task_id",
```

It can work on first row.

However I want to do this for every row.

How can I do this?

Comment: With a `for` loop and a change to the `jq '.taskArns[0]'` part? What have you tried?

Comment: Note that awscli has some useful features built-in to get the raw values: `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s --query "taskArns" --output text` and you can iterate over that with a simple for loop: `for t in (aws ec2 ...); do echo $t; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter your JQ command by looping over the items (`[]`), then use `split()` and `[-1]` to select the task id's:

```
jq -r '.taskArns[] | split("/")[-1]'
```

This gives us a list of the task id's:

```
1f3761101efd439f9d8959901e8f6095
2bfb7cdfb9e64362b4df6b7f7e829236
408879277ab24490b1b911b119c81414
```

---

Afterwards you can [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950596/iterating-through-json-array-in-shell-script) over the result using `.. | while read task_id; do`:

```
jq -r '.taskArns[] | split("/")[-1]' "$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s )" \   
    |  while read task_id; do 
           aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster dev-ec2-cls --tasks "$task_id";
       done
```

Comment: Probably use `jq -r` to get rid of the pesky double quotes around the values.

Comment: It works for my purpose `jq -r`! thank you very much

Comment: possibly also `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s | jq -r '.taskArns[] | split("/")[-1]' | xargs aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster dev-ec2-cls --tasks`. Also `jq -r '.taskArns[] | split("/")[-1]' "$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster dev-ec2s )"` is not valid way to pass JSON data to JQ. Either stream it from a pipe, either pass it as `--argjson`